# Accessing to the release artifact on TeamCity

Tags: android, teamcity

A couple days ago i finished with TC setup and started work on projects building setup.

Now i succed in automated debug building from the develop branch, but my aim is also get RC builds from the master or release brunch.

To get visible debug builds i use "Artifact paths: */build/outputs/apk/*.apk => ."

For RC i tried this value "*/*.apk => .", because AndroidStudio place signed build directly into module folder. But in this case i can't see any artifacts after successful building.

Does anybody gets RC builds by the means on TC?

Comment: What do you see in the build logs. Have you checked on the build agent to confirm that apk exists at the location provided in the artifacts path.

Comment: I can't see anything usefull in the build logs. It's just successfull logs for application building process.

One thing I want to add is when I use "Artifact paths: /build/outputs/apk/.apk => ." with release building I can see release apk file in the artifacts. But this file isn't signed with my release key, and it's a normal case, because Gradle generates separate signed build.
So the question is: "Where TC put's release, signed apk file?"